Django Session variables not visible after login
I am developing a hospital site. patients are allowed to login and book appointment. When a patient logs in, a sessions is initiated and saved. Again, I debugged, by adding a print statement after saving the sessions in the login view and its good, but when i try to book an appointment, then i print the session variables, they are empty. Could anyone please help me on this.... I would really appreciate.
Note: My frontend is built with Next.js and am adding credentials='include' on my request. Also the cookies are set well in my browser with the key: sessionid and its value.
const response = await fetch(
            "http://127.0.0.1:8000/bookings/book-appointment/",
            {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(appointmentData),
              credentials: "include"
            }
          );

@csrf_exempt
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            email = data.get('email')
            password = data.get('password')

            # Fetch the user from the database
            user = Patient.objects.filter(email=email).first()

            # Check if user exists and password is correct
            if user and user.check_password(password):
                
                # Handle 2FA if enabled
                if user.enable_2fa:
                    generate_and_send_2fa_code(user)
                    return JsonResponse({
                        'success': True,
                        'message': '2FA code sent',
                        'user_id': user.id,
                        'email': user.email,
                        'requires_2fa': True
                    })

                # Set session expiry time
                request.session.set_expiry(2 * 60 * 60)  # 2 hours

                # Log the user in and save the session
                login(request, user)

                # Set a cookie for the session ID
                response = JsonResponse({
                    'success': True,
                    'message': 'Login successful. Welcome!',
                    'user_id': user.id,
                    'email': user.email,
                    'session_id': request.session.session_key
                })
                response.set_cookie(
                    key='sessionid',
                    value=request.session.session_key,
                    max_age=2 * 60 * 60, 
                 )
                request.session.save()
                print("Login Session data:", request.session.items())
                print("Login Session ID:", request.session.session_key)
                
                return response
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid credentials'})

        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'message': f'An error occurred: {str(e)}'})

    return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid request method'})

@csrf_exempt
def book_appointment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Debugging: Print session data and session ID
        print("Session data:", request.session.items())
        print("Session ID:", request.session.session_key)
        request.session.modified = True # Here

        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)

            # Extract data from the session
            user_id = request.session.get('user_id')
            patient_email = request.session.get('email')

            if not user_id or not patient_email:
                return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'message': 'User not authenticated'}, status=401)

            # Extract other data from the request
            doctor_name = data.get('doctorName')
            speciality = data.get('speciality')
            date = data.get('date')
            time = data.get('time')
            period = data.get('period')
            consultation_type = data.get('consultationType')
            problem_description = data.get('problemDescription')
            patient_name = data.get('patientName')  # Or use the patient's name from session
            doctor_image = data.get('doctor_image')

            # Check if the patient has already booked an appointment with the same doctor at the same time
            existing_appointment = Appointment.objects.filter(
                doctor_name=doctor_name,
                date=date,
                time=time,
                patient_email=patient_email
            ).first()

            if existing_appointment:
                return JsonResponse({
                    'status': 'error',
                    'message': 'You already have an appointment with this doctor at this time.'
                }, status=400)

            # Check if the doctor is already booked for that time
            doctor_appointment = Appointment.objects.filter(
                doctor_name=doctor_name,
                date=date,
                time=time
            ).exists()

            if doctor_appointment:
                return JsonResponse({
                    'status': 'error',
                    'message': 'The doctor is not available at this time. Please choose another time slot.'
                }, status=400)

            # Save the new appointment to the database
            appointment = Appointment.objects.create(
                doctor_name=doctor_name,
                speciality=speciality,
                date=date,
                time=time,
                period=period,
                consultation_type=consultation_type,
                problem_description=problem_description,
                patient_name=patient_name,  # You might also use a session-stored patient name
                patient_email=patient_email,
                doctor_image=doctor_image
            )

            return JsonResponse({
                'status': 'success',
                'appointment_id': appointment.id,
                'message': 'You have successfully booked an appointment!'
            })

        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'message': 'Invalid JSON'}, status=400)

    return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'message': 'Invalid request method'}, status=400)

And this is my settings as well

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    'patients',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'authentication',
    'allauth',
    'bookAppointments',
    'timelines',
    'chats',
    'doctorsnotes',
    'medication',
    'noticeboard',
    'online_doctors',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]


SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'patients.middleware.DisableCSRF', 
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]


You are showing us the API call for booking an appointment and it has credentials: "include" are you also doing that for your login request?

Yes, right here:  axios           .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/login/", { email, password }, {             withCredentials: true          })

Uhh, why are you using axios for that call and fetch for the one you're having issues with? Can you try using the same function for both API calls?

Hmm, what is the value of the SameSite attribute of your cookies when you check them in the browser's devtools?

Okay, I am changing to use fetch instead. The samesite says Lax

Ah, yes Lax won't work for cross site requests, you'll need it to be None and the cookie should be Secure as well.

Thanks bro. I changed and it worked. CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None' SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
